# Вывод каждого третьего числа начиная с 1 в Джава скрипте

Tags: javascript

Эта функция с циклом выводит числа, добавляяя к нему сумму предыдущих.

```
function getDrinks(guests) {
  // write code here
  let sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= guests; i++){
    sum += i;
  }
    return sum;
}
```

Теперь мне нужно, чтобы начиная с числа 1, выводились числа через 3 и добавлялись к сумме предыщущих. Например, если число 10, то дожна вывестись  сумма чисел кратных через 3, то есть 1, 4, 7, 10, и сумма будет равнятся 22. Как мне для этого модернизировать предыдущий цикл в  функции??????? Знаю, что нужно ввести второй параметр step.

```
function getDrinks(guests, step) {
  // write code here
  let sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= guests; i++){
    sum += i;
  }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: то что вы считаете вообще называется суммой арифметической прогрессии. есть формула для ее подсчета без цикла. Но если вы хотите сделать это циклом, то `i=1;....; i+=3`

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать деление с остатком для проверки кратности `i` в текущей итерации:

```js
function getDrinks(guests, step) {
  let sum = 0;
  // i = 0 изменено на i = 1, т.к. sum += 0 ничего не меняет
  // Добавление указанного шага к i
  for (i = 1; i <= guests; i+=step){
    sum += i;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

### Большое спасибо  Эникейщик за подсказку. Код был переработан. Шаг прибавляется к i на каждой итерации

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Можно, но не оптимально. Подсказка: инкремент в цикле совсем необязательно должен быть вида i++. Очень жаль, что очень многие об этом не помнят, а то и не знают.